# Get values in form of 1-5,6-10... and so on till 50 in Combo Box

Tags: c#

```
for (int i = 0; i <50 ; i++)
{
    cb.Items.Add(i);
}
```

Here it shows all values until 49 in vertical format but I want in range

> 1-5 ,6-10,11-15

and next

Comment: and what is yout question??

Comment: for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i += 5)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString() + "-" + (i+4).ToString());
            }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll want to change the increment for the loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 50; i += 5)
{
    cb.Items.Add($"{i}-{i + 4}");
}
```

Comment: Perfect!Thanks a lot... :)

Comment: It works perfectly for visual 15,but in 2008 visual it's showing  $ as unspecified

Comment: @user7388587 Yeah, interpolated strings are a C# 6 feature. You can use `cb.Items.Add(string.Format("{0}-{1}", i, i + 4));` in 2008 instead.

Comment: Thank you  I need another query  I need  in range of  5,multiple  but  if my last Value 47 it must show  till 47 instead of  50